# angular add package to package.json file make error in compile time in StoreModule.forRoot syntax

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, package.json

angular add package to package.json file make error in compile time in StoreModule.forRoot syntax

i added a new library to my package.json file [image] , then the compile time has error in this code

```
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers,{
  metaReducers,
  runtimeChecks: {
    strictStateImmutability: true,
    strictActionImmutability: true
  }
}),
```

the error is

```
Type 'ModuleWithProviders<StoreRootModule>' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any> | ModuleWithProviders<{}>'.   Type 'ModuleWithProviders<StoreRootModule>' is not assignable to type 'ModuleWithProviders<{}>'.     Types of property 'providers' are incompatible.       Type '(Provider | EnvironmentProviders)[]' is not assignable to type 'Provider[]'.         Type 'Provider | EnvironmentProviders' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.           Type 'EnvironmentProviders' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
```

you can see the code here
[image]

can someone help with knowing the cause of this ? how to fix it ? i tried to try other versions but not working

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a `@ngrx/store` dependency in the packages.
Make sure that it's installed and on v14.3.2